# Data added to datagrid not visible in UI in WPF in MVP

Tags: wpf, datagridview

In a WPF application,

I  have to display data to a log window using data grid..

Every log message should be added to the logwindow and needs to be displayed.

My Xaml is :

```
  <ListView x:Name="lstViewLogWindow" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="152" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" MouseEnter="lstViewLogWindow_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="lstViewLogWindow_MouseLeave" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>

                <GridView x:Name="grdViewLogWindow" >
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Message" Header="MessageDetails" Width="1000" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= MessageDetails}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="LogDate" Header="DateTime" Width="275" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= DateTime}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I have a LogMessage.cs class as

```
 public class LogMessage
{
   public string Message_Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
}
```

In the code behind...

```
public void showmsg(string msg) {

        List<LogMessage> messages    = new List<LogMessage>();
    messages.Add(new LogMessage() { LogTime = DateTime.Now, Message_Name = msg });
            lstViewLogWindow.DataContext = messages;}
```

I am able to see the data available in the 'messages'... but I couldnt see it in the UI...

my presenter has `_view.showmsg(msg)`........

But I cant see the data int he log window.. 
Please help..
thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 1):

Your ListView's ItemsSource is set to {Binding}.  However, you did not show where you are setting the DataContext of your view.  So, first, in your code-behind file, you need the following:

```
this.DataContext = messages;
```

In addition, your columns are bound to incorrect property names.  Currently:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= MessageDetails}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= DateTime}"
```

Should be:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message_Name}"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LogTime}"
```